# Variable inside subquery not receiving variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have never tried to pass a variable value into a subquery before, and I seem to be going about it wrong.  I am not receiving any errors, but I also get no results, whereas if I hard-code the values for startdate, enddate & role into the subquery, it runs correctly.

================edit =======================

My bad, I posted the earlier test script I was playing with which was indeed full of errors, sorry for that.  Here is the actual code I am working with, in full:

```
DECLARE @Role varchar,
    @StartDate datetime,
    @Enddate datetime;

SET     @Role = 'Volunteer';
SET     @StartDate = DATEADD(d, -100, getdate());
SET     @Enddate = getdate();

SELECT rolename, Category, [1] as [1 Day],[2] as [2 Days],[3] as [3 Days],[4] as [4 Days],[5] as [5 Days],[6] as [6 Days],[7] as [7 Days]  FROM
(SELECT    CriminalHistoryID, vps.RoleName, 'Rec2PreClr' as Category,
        DATEDIFF(d, chc.ReceiveDate, chc.PreClrDate) as DaysDif
  FROM  dbo.v_PersonStatus vps
              INNER JOIN dbo.CriminalHistoryCheck chc
                    ON vps.PersonID = chc.PersonID
  WHERE chc.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate AND vps.rolename = @Role and DATEDIFF(d, chc.ReceiveDate, chc.PreClrDate) BETWEEN 0 and 7
  UNION
  SELECT      CriminalHistoryID, vps.RoleName, 'PreClr2Clr' as Category,
              DATEDIFF(d, chc.PreClrDate, chc.FinalDate) as DaysDif
  FROM  dbo.v_PersonStatus vps
              INNER JOIN dbo.CriminalHistoryCheck chc
                    ON vps.PersonID = chc.PersonID
  WHERE chc.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate AND vps.rolename = @Role AND DATEDIFF(d, chc.PreClrDate, chc.FinalDate) BETWEEN 0 and 7
  UNION
  SELECT      CriminalHistoryID, vps.RoleName, 'Rec2Clr' as Category,
              DATEDIFF(d, chc.ReceiveDate, FinalDate) as DaysDif
  FROM  dbo.v_PersonStatus vps
              INNER JOIN dbo.CriminalHistoryCheck chc
                    ON vps.PersonID = chc.PersonID
  WHERE chc.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate AND vps.rolename = @Role AND DATEDIFF(d, chc.ReceiveDate, FinalDate) BETWEEN 0 and 7
  ) UNIONqry
PIVOT
(count(CriminalHistoryID) for DaysDif in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) pvt
Order by RoleName, Category
```

The values for @Startdate, @Enddate & @Role do not seem to be getting into the subquery.  Do I need to do something to tell the sub to look outside the box?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you sure you are running *all* the code at the same time?  You can't run the `declare` and then run the subquery -- the definitions only last while for the statement that is running.

Comment: It looks like this isn't all of the code - there's a UNION there. If you ran all of this as written here, it would fail with a syntax error.

Comment: If you don't set @VolStatus, it will be NULL. Depending on your ANSI_NULL setting, you may or may not get data... I'm guessing this might be your problem though.

Comment: Please, you really shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types, [especially on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Really, it's the wrong way to think about time, regardless of any... irregularities the RDBMS may have.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - What should I do instead?

Comment: @teahou - follow the recommendations in the linked blog-post; basically, always use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`).  The basic idea is - you should always plan/write/store things as if they suddenly had the ability to be more precise (this applies to more than timestamps).  If the bound is inclusive, you have to do more juggling to make sure the extra precision is handled properly.  If it's exclusive, you need to do nothing (pretty much).

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You're not assigning a value to volStatus
2. It should be `@volstatus` and not `@ volstatus` - no space

So, change:

```
WHERE chc.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate AND vps.rolename = @ VolStatus and DATEDIFF(d, chc.ReceiveDate, chc.PreClrDate) BETWEEN 0 and 7
```

To:

```
WHERE chc.ReceiveDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @Enddate AND vps.rolename = @VolStatus and DATEDIFF(d, chc.ReceiveDate, chc.PreClrDate) BETWEEN 0 and 7
```